# do I always need an access token to make a request with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The question raises because I was reading a book about Facebook Application development and when it explains how to make call to the graph, it says that I can verifiy how simply I can retrieve informations from the graph just writitng https://graph.facebook.com/myProfileId in my web browser. Well, I do that but I get this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (myusername)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

but then if I include in the url an access token generated from the Graph API explorer, I can see the JSON with more informations, as I expected to be.

The question is: do I always need an access token to make a request with the Facebook Graph API even if the informations that I want to access are public? In case of affirmative answer to this question, why the book I'm reading says I can get informations from the graph even without an access token? Maybe this is a feature of an older version of the graph api?

Comment: How old is the book? All calls need an access token since v2.0, which was announced in April 2014 and became mandatory for existing apps in April 2015

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need a token, the token is intrinsically linked to a specific user.

How could you retreive any informations (even public) with only a generic Url,
you must add to the request an information to identify the user that you want.

Personally I use this link `"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="` from the facebook doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview